# Condition on Angular HHTP Request

Tags: angular, httprequest

Can you use conditions, with Angular subscribe function ?
Like, in this code :

```
   this.http.post<any>(phpUrl, content)
.subscribe(
    (r) => {
      if(r.message) // That's how the target script actually manages errors
      { 
        console.log(r.message);
        this.handleErrorPhp(r, formData.email);
      }
      else
      {
        this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { register: true } });
      }
    },
    (error) => {
      this.handleErrorPhp(error, formData.email);
    }
  );
```

I'd like too navigate to the login page, when the script doesn't catch any error. But, even when the "r.message" is empty, my code bugs and stops, telling me r.message is not defined.

EDIT : Here is the console error log :

```
ERROR TypeError: can't access property "message", i is null
```

Comment: Does the error message say `r.message` is undefined or is `r` undefined? You don't seem to check if `r` is defined before accessing it's property `message`.

Comment: Please, code  ;(r) => {console.log(r)... and add the console response to your question

Comment: It says : "ERROR TypeError: can't access property "message", i is null". Since, it seems the scripts switches to the error case when r is undefined.

Comment: Where does `i` come from? Is `r.message` a getter property?

Comment: I don't know... it's from Angular native scripts I guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say check if `r` is defined before trying to access it's property `message`. More info about the double-bang operator [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/784946/6513921).

```js
this.http.post<any>(phpUrl, content).subscribe(
  (r: any) => {
    if (!!r && !!r.message) { 
      console.log(r.message);
      this.handleErrorPhp(r, formData.email);
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { register: true } });
    }
  },
  (error: any) => {
     this.handleErrorPhp(error, formData.email);
  }
);
```

Comment: It seems to work well, thank you !